# Showing memory location instead of value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a block of this code in my helper:

```
if !shop.directions.blank?
     "<ul>".html_safe +
        shop.directions.each do |direction|
          "<li>#{direction.direction}</li>".html_safe
        end +
     "</ul>".html_safe
else
    "No directions available.".html_safe
end +
```

It's showing memory location of `direction.direction` like

```
#<Direction:0xab3c6d0>#<Direction:0xa32c6d0>
```

instead of the value of it like

```
1. Take bus no. 3
2. Take train towards Lydia Ave.
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

Now I changed it to this:

```
spot.directions.flatten.map do |direction|
          "<li>".html_safe + direction.direction + "</li>".html_safe
        end
```

using the `flatten.map`. But then, it shows the entire code on the browser:

```
 <li>Take bus no. 3</li><li>Take train towards Lydia Ave.</li>
```

Yes, including the `<li><li>`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're storing a Direction object (that doesn't have a custom to_s method) in direction.direction, instead of a string. Try outputting direction.direction.inspect to get a better idea of what's going on. Also keep in mind that ruby-debug can be a great tool over debugging by printing out values.

My guess, without looking at the code, would be that you might have an array of arrays of direction objects, like `[[direction1],[direction2]]` instead of the flattened array that you're expecting `[direction1, direction2]`.

**Update:** Array#map returns another array -- what you want to do is build up a string, not return an array, so consider either explicitly building up the string, or calling join on the resultant array.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's better for me to just forget about putting it in helper, but in the view instead. Save more troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Your block seems to be fine, did you check what kind of object `Direction#direction` returns? If it returns a `Direction` object, then that's exactly what you would get.

**Answer for your update:** Any combined/reconstructed string loses its "html safe" status, and it gets escaped on the output. You should call `html_safe` on the final result, and inside the block, escape risky strings manually with `h(risky_part)`

Comment: I'm sorry, removing .html_safe or adding it doesn't solve the problem. <li></li> is still shown in the output. It's like a "pre" text now.

Comment: I meant that your helper function should return like `return result.html_safe`

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's better for me to just forget about putting it in helper, but in the view instead. Save more troubles.